# Can not delegate twig templating on Symfony 3.10 and above - memory exhausted

Tags: symfony

I am trying to deletage the twig templating on Symfony 3.3.10 to a custom DelegatingEngine class but php always gives me a memory exhausted error.

Following documentation this is what I understand, but gives me a 500 server error (looking at logs: memory exhausted)

```
app.twig_delegating_engine.delegating_engine:
    class: AppBundle\Twig\DelegatingEngine\DelegatingEngine
    parent: templating.engine.delegating

templating.engine.delegating:
    alias: app.twig_delegating_engine.delegating_engine
```

Using a compiler pass only works for Symfony 3.3.9 but not for Symfony 3.3.10 and above.

```
public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $definition = $container->getDefinition('templating.engine.delegating');
    $definition->setClass(\AppBundle\Twig\DelegatingEngine\DelegatingEngine::class);

}
```

The above yml configuration does not work on Symfony 3.3.9.

Comment: Both Symfony 3.9 and 3.10 do not exist.

Comment: Sorry mate, I meant 3.3.9 and 3.3.10, I fixed it, thank you!